Which subsets of the symmetric group $S_n$ can be generated by $log_2(n)$ levels of pairwise swaps?
I am interested in the properties of all members of the symmetric group $S_n$, where $n$ is a power of 2 ($n = 2^l$ for $l \in \mathbb{N}$), which can be generated by $l=log_2(n)$ levels of pairwise swaps. On each level, pairs of elements that are $2^l/2$ elements apart in the sequence being generated can either be swapped or not. Specifically, on level $l$ the element at position $i < 2^l/2$ in the sequence may be swapped with the element at position $i + 2^l/2$ (elements at positions $2^l \le i < 2^l \cdot \frac{3}{2}$ may then again be swapped with elements at $i + 2^l/2$, and so forth).
At each level, there are $n/2$ pairs, each of which may be swapped or not. Hence, each level can permute the sequence in $2^{n/2}$ different ways. All levels combined, $2^{l \cdot n/2} = n \cdot 2^{n/2}$ of the $n!$ members of $S_n$ can be generated that way.
Example:
For instance, consider the subset of $S_4$ that can be generated. Starting from the identity permutation $(1,2,3,4)$:

On level 1, the elements at positions 1 and 2 may be swapped, as well as the elements at positions 3 and 4.
On level 2, the elements at positions 1 and 3 may be swapped, as well as the elements at positions 2 and 4.

Therefore, level 1 may produce any of the four following intermediate sequences: $(1,2,3,4)$, $(2,1,3,4)$, $(1,2,4,3)$, or $(2,1,4,3)$, by swapping neither pair, the first pair, the second pair, or both pairs, respectively.
Level 2 produces the final sequence, which may be, among others:

Any of the circular shifts of all four sequence elements: $(1,2,3,4)$, $(4,1,2,3)$, $(3,4,1,2)$, or $(2,3,4,1)$.
The inverse $(4,3,2,1)$ of the initial 4-cycle, as well as any circular shift of all four elements of that inverse: $(1,4,3,2)$, $(2,1,4,3)$, or $(3,2,1,4)$.

In total, 16 of the 24 members of $S_4$ can be generated that way. Which subset (or possibly multiple subsets) is this?
Question:
In general, what are the properties of the subset of $S_n$ that this method can generate? Is there a specific name for the subset (or for some of the subsets it contains)? Which elements of $S_n$ are not part of that subset and why?

Background:
The method described above allows to rotate a sequence of $n$ elements (i.e., produce any of the circular shifts of all $n$ elements) in $log_2(n)$ levels of pairwise swapping. Therefore, it is frequently used in logic design as a rotation circuit (in logic design it is usually desirable to reduce the number of logic levels and conditionally swapping two elements is implemented as a 2:1 multiplexer, which has a logic depth of 1, so a rotation circuit built that way has a total of $log_2(n)$ logic levels). However, while such a circuit can be used for rotations, it could also be used to generate a few other permutations of $S_n$ without adding any complexity and I am wondering whether there might be some more that are useful (i.e., whether the same circuit could be used for other relevant operations and not just for rotations).
